# What did the Levi'im sing in the Bet Hamikdash?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, music, levites-leviyim

From [Talmud Tamid 7:4](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Tamid.7.4?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) we know that each day, the Levi'im sang a different Psalm.

What else did they sing? Did they sing the same Psalms daily, and did they use the same tunes?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29665/759